Is there an alternative way to run succesfully a .java program without commenting the package name line?
I created a simple java program on netbeans and it working just fine when I execute it within the Netbeans IDE. However, this is the issue I'm dealing with:
I'm getting this error when running the program after compiling with "javac" using the command line, specifically bash on fedora:
java EjerciciosClase 

Error: Could not find or load main class EjerciciosClase
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/estudio/ejerciciosclase/EjerciciosClase (wrong name: EjerciciosClase)

I was able to solve it by commenting the package name line:
package com.estudio.ejerciciosclase;

I have removed the line from package and it seems to be working.
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package com.estudio.ejerciciosclase;
import java.util.Scanner; // import the scanner class
/**
 *
 * @author jfac
 * 
 */
public class sumScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numA, numB, theSum;
        System.out.println("Program that reads y sums two numbers");
        
        Scanner newObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");   
        numA = newObj.nextInt();
        //String numAString = Integer.toString(numA);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        numB = newObj.nextInt();
        //String numBString = Integer.toString(numB);
        theSum = numA + numB;
       // String theSumString = Integer.toString(theSum);
        
        System.out.println("The sum of " + numA + " + " +  numB + " is equal to " + theSum);
    }
}


is there any alternative way to run this program without removing the package name line? I'd like to run programs both on netbeans IDE and BASH terminal without modifying the code.

your class name is sumScanner, not EjerciciosClase

You are correct, package com.estudio.ejerciciosclase and public class sumScanner. However, that does not resolve the issue.

If there is just one package, then you should be able to do (from the project directory) javac -d build/classes src/com/estudio/ejerciciosclase/*.java;java com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner If not, you should provide the path to each package to javac. This is why build tools are necessary normally ;) btw, class names should begin upper case
in Java

@Juan your question is being voted-to-close because what you say cannot possibly be true. You are not running that file with java EjerciciosClase. You're running it either with java EjerciciosClase.java which is a very different mode, or you are running it with java sumScanner, or you're running a different file. We can't help you if the question is ambiguous, confusing, and/or inconsistent.

continuation from previous comment: the CLASSPATH (environment variable) must contain the build/classes directory; or be empty and working directory be build/classes to use java com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner; If that is not the case, use java -classpath build/classes com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner

@user85421: good catch. -cpor -classpath must be set to the value build/classes with what I recommended or it will fail.

@rzwitserloot's comment - my comment was regarding this comment - I rephrase: java com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner will only work if: 1) the working directory is build/classes and the CLASSPATH environment variable is empty or contains .;  or 2) the CLASSPATH env-var. contains the build/classes directory. This is NOT A SUGGESTION, just a fact. Use: java -cp build/classes com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner

@Juan check the documentation of java - search for -classpath; or try How the Java Launcher Finds User Classes -- neither my English nor my Spanish are good enough to explain it, sorry

I tried:
"javac SumScanner.java"
and then:
java SumScanner
Not working.
I will try and read your comments. Thank you in advance. I will let you know if it works.

I think you'd better read them ;) That's not even the name of the class, let alone the package

@Juan, javac needs the file (example javac sumScanner.java) ; java needs a full class name (example java com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner) || Alternative since Java 11, without compiling (explicitly) and single file only: java with file (example java sumScanner.java)

As @ the class you shared is called 'sumScanner' , not 'EjerciciosClase'. Your class is in a subdirectory that matches the package structure. If you are commenting the package and it works, then you are executing a class called 'EjerciciosClase' that is at the top of the sources directory instead of a subpackage. To execute a class in a package you need to add the package: java com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner.
By Java naming convention the class name should start with an uppercase letter but that is unrelated to the issue. You should follow the Java convention so you should rename the class to something like SumScanner, and also the file name to match.

I'm getting this error  "java com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner
Error: Could not find or load main class com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.sumScanner
"

Are you sure it is in the package directory and already compiled it?

I forgot to capitalize the Class, thank you!

Are you sure it is in the package directory and already compiled it?  Yes. I have tried the following:
javac SumScanner.java
Then to run it:
java com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.SumScanner
Error:
Could not find or load main class com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.SumScanner
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.estudio.ejerciciosclase.SumScanner

From which directory are you running both commands?
